# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field in controller extension

Tags: apex, soql, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I have written this controller extension:

```
public with sharing class PopupController {
    ApexPages.Standardcontroller cont;
    public Request_Change_Reseller__c req{get;set;}

    public PopupController(ApexPages.StandardController cont){
    this.cont = cont;
    req=new Request_Change_Reseller__c();
    req.PartnerUserId__c = ((Lead)cont.getRecord()).Assigned_to_Partner__c;

    }

    public PageReference save(){

    return null;
    }

}
```

My visualforce page is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="PopupController" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:outputField label="Lead" value="{!Lead.Name}"/>
  <apex:inputField label="Assign To Partner" value="{! req.PartnerUserId__c}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I created a custom button in the  lead layout. When I click on it a new window opens and I get this error:

```
SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Lead.Assigned_to_Partner__c .
```

Can I not access all fields in a controller extension? Will I have to make a soql query?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A standardcontroller's record will only contain the fields referenced in the visualforce page you're using it on. The standard controller addFields(List) method ([docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm)) allows you to extend this to the fields you need in your apex code.

```
cont.addFields(new List<String>{'Assigned_to_Partner__c'});
```

Set this as the 2nd line in your constructor.

Comment: Dunno if it was the case when you wrote this, but worth noting this method cannot be called from a test.

Answer (score 4):

A field has to be on the page to be included - so as well as using addfields, you can also just add the field in an output panel with rendered set to false - it should then be included in the SOQL